# Sublime Text 2 won't run Java

Tags: java, compilation, sublimetext2

I recently have gotten Sublime Text 2 and I had a few headaches so far, the biggest one being from this:

```
public class bob{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("Sublime Text 2!");

    }

}
```

because it won't run at all. It just won't run. I press F7 and nothing happens, except it outputs this:

```
[Finished in *s]
```

and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default Java build system does not run your program after compilation.

If you open `...\Packages\Java\JavaC.sublime-build` and replace the content of the build system file with:

```js
{
  "cmd": ["javac", "$file_name","&&","java", "$file_base_name"],
  "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
  "selector": "source.java",
  "shell": true
}
```

**EDIT:** in the above you need to concatenate multiple commands for the shell to execute because the build system does not support listing multiple commands by itself.

Then it will compile and run your program when you build ( <kbd>F7</kbd> ).

This is a very simplistic build system and will only work for simple programs obviously.

Comment: It says "Could not find or load main class bob"

Comment: @user1610406 checkout my updated answer (it only worked for me before because I manually compiled the file prior running the build system to test)

Comment: @Strelok I love you, dude !

Comment: For Sublime Text 3, a little modification had to be done:

`{`
  `"cmd": "javac $file_name && java $file_base_name",`
  `"working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",`
  `"selector": "source.java",`
  `"shell": true`
`}`

This works permectly on ST3 on a Mac

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution to run java in sublime 2:

Make the bat file with the following, and save it anywhere in your PATH. I suggest C:\Program Files\Java\jdk*\bin\ to keep everything together.

```
@ECHO OFF
cd %~dp1
javac %~nx1
java %~n1
```

then edit C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Java\JavaC.sublime-build, the contents will be

```
{
   "cmd": ["javac", "$file"],
   "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
   "selector": "source.java"
}
```

replace "javac" with the name of your bat file (for instance, javacexec.bat) and save it.

Now you should be able to run it using ctrl+b.